# Is it possible to have Python code snippets in Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, stack-snippets

Is it currently possible to have Python snippets on Stack Overflow?

Python is getting increasingly popular and is also currently the most tagged language in Stack Overflow. It has got 1177 questions asked just today at 9:30!

I did google it, and I found [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323179/please-can-we-have-runnable-python-snippets-using-skulpt) and [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/327741/support-running-snippets-in-languages-other-than-just-javascript) post, but it *was* asked four years ago. Surely, technology has updated since then? I am a relatively recent coder, but I read in the post and I have heard in other places that it is possible using [Skulpt](http://skulpt.org/).

Comment: It's already possible with DataCamp in Stack Snippets, to a limited extent https://stackoverflow.com/a/53422775 but I'm doubtful backend languages are that suitable for being made runnable on SO - it's possible with a lot of work, but it's pretty complicated. Pasting the code and linking to someplace like https://ideone.com/ might be better

Comment: Keep in mind that the major difference between JS snippets and other languages is that JS can be executed online without implementing or otherwise downloading an entire Python interpreter. If we can't have basic MathJAX over size constraints, I highly doubt this will be implemented.

Comment: You should also keep in mind how many different requirements can be required to run a python script and SO (or any other website) shouldn't be expected to keep them all on hand so that scripts can be run in a post.

Comment: "Technology" isn't really the problem here, it's domain. Most JS can be run in a browser, node.js, cannot be because its domain is more than just web. It would be like asking to be able to run iOS code on a non-apple computer. It *can* be done, but the tool chain is ridiculous. Allowing snippets is much easier (although still not without security concerns) and maintaining it is easy as well because no update to JS would ever make JS unrunnable on the web.

Comment: If the purpose of a runnable snippet is so that a reader can click "play" and see the output, what is the benefit of this over just requiring people to include the output in their post as static text? With Javascript snippets at least the "input" and "output" might involve GUI interaction and DOM manipulation, but Python code cannot naturally accept input or produce output via a browser. Would runnable Python snippets also require a terminal emulator to be embedded in the post?

Comment: Could you please edit to clarify what *new information* this feature request brings over existing once? Something like recommending client-side Python VM... that was not suggested before?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I don't have any suggestions for how the implementation should be done. What I have that add more information to the other requests are the reasons for why the snippet should be done for Python language, which I stated in the questions in total 3 reasons, all of which has legit references. I only suggest that it should be done, but I do not concern on how it is done.

Comment: Python relies a lot on third-party packages, has many use-cases that require using OS resources like files, sockets, and so on, and often has implementation/compiler/tooling specific questions. These are usually things a "runnable snippet" cannot support at all, or at least not well. How many Q&As would benefit from runnable snippets at all? For every question improved, how many will be worse because the author picked the wrong code kind of code/snippet or wasted time before figuring out what works?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is not feasible.

Stack snippets *run entirely in the browser*. You can't run Python in everyone's browser, not the CPython (main) implementation.

Python is a very, *very* rich ecosystem, with [multiple implementations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17130986/100297), and while there [are implementations](https://skulpt.org/) [that run](https://pyodide.org/) [in a browser](https://brython.info/), these are far from complete nor can they run many of the libraries that make Python so popular, such as NumPy and Pandas for data science <sup>*)</sup>, or Flask, Django or Quart for web applications, or Tkinter, Qt and GTK for GUIs.

Nor do I feel it is necessary; I have been answering Python questions for over 12 years on this site without the need for snippets. It's not like Python is regularly used to create dynamic HTML and style output, the way JavaScript is, for example.

---

<sup>*)</sup> Yes, Pyodide can run much of the data science stable of libraries, but has [no working threads, sockets or multiprocessing support](https://pyodide.org/en/stable/usage/wasm-constraints.html#included-but-not-working-modules), which in my view is a severe limitation. It is also [resource heavy](https://pyodide.org/en/stable/project/roadmap.html#reducing-download-sizes-and-initialization-times), something the Stack Overflow team has tried to avoid in the past.

Answer (score 13):

I completely agree with the answer of Martijn Pieters.

> Stack snippets run entirely in the browser. You can't run Python in everyone's browser, not the CPython (main) implementation.

Sometimes we need to demonstrate some code that does not require OS-bound kinds of stuff or drivers. The [PyScript](https://github.com/pyscript/pyscript#readme) with help of [Pyodide](https://github.com/pyodide/pyodide#readme) gives the ability to run Python code in a browser.

> PyScript is a meta project that aims to combine multiple open technologies into a framework that allows users to create sophisticated browser applications with Python. It integrates seamlessly with the way the DOM works in the browser and allows users to add Python logic in a way that feels natural both to web and Python developers.

Yes, it cannot run threads, processes, or sockets and has limitations, but it can execute such third-party libraries as [Beautiful Soup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beautiful_Soup), [Bokeh](https://bokeh.org/), [Matplotlib](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matplotlib), [Natural Language Toolkit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_Language_Toolkit) (NLTK), [NumPy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NumPy), [Pandas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pandas_%28software%29), [Pillow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_Imaging_Library), [SciPy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SciPy), [SQLAlchemy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQLAlchemy), [scikit-learn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scikit-learn), etc.

Pyodide uses [WebLoop](https://pyodide.org/en/stable/usage/api/python-api.html#pyodide.webloop.WebLoop) as the main event loop so that we can execute asynchronous functions as well.

```js
import asyncio
import numpy as np

async def func():
    for i in range(2, 7):
        await asyncio.sleep(.5)
        print(np.random.randint(i, size=10))

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(func())
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/pysnippet/pysnippet@latest/snippet.min.js"></script>
```

As you can see, it is enough to add the [PySnippet](https://github.com/pysnippet/pysnippet#readme) [CDN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network) as an external library and run a Python snippet.

Also, note that I have used NumPy without installing it as the PySnippet has been made to solve the auto setup of initialization requirements for easy use.

Comment: If there are newlines in the output (which can happen for example if there are Python errors), the output is more readable if you add `py-script{white-space:pre;}` to the CSS.

Answer (score -6):

EDIT: I use [Pyscript](https://pyscript.net/) for the example (to make the example much simpler) - powered by [Pyodide](https://pyodide.org) - "Python with the scientific stack, compiled to WebAssembly."

I hope Stack Overflow will enable Python as official code snippets soon, but currently if you using python with scientific stack (and not with gui) Pyodide can be used from Stack Snippets.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pyscript.net/alpha/pyscript.css" />
        <script defer src="https://pyscript.net/alpha/pyscript.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<py-script>
    # Python code here
    import random
    print("Generate random integers between 0 and 9 in python:", random.randint(1, 10), sep="\n") # SO: 3996904
</py-script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is *"js playground"*? A [generic one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_online_source_code_playgrounds#Online_web_client-side_source_code_playgrounds)? Or a particular one? Stack Snippets here on Stack Overflow? Can you elaborate?

Comment: Pyodide is nice, but would it be a net benefit for [so]? It supports one out of five Python releases (not counting older versions, PyPy and things like Cython), [lacks some prominent libraries](https://pyodide.org/en/stable/usage/wasm-constraints.html#included-but-not-working-modules) and while the scientific stack has many users, Python is used for a lot of other things – that often involve things the browser just cannot supply. For every code snippet improved by this, how many will be worse because the author picked the wrong code kind or wasted time before figuring out what works?

Comment: This snippet isn't working, it just shows me "out of memory" errors.

Comment: pyodide work with WebAssembly... so your webbrowser may not support it or your webbrowser not config enough memory for python dist caching

Comment: Pyodide can't run threads, multiprocessing or sockets. It's a great project, but those are three honking great limitations that would cut out a huge swathe of questions and answers in the Python ecosystem.

Answer (score -6):

As the answers above said, this is possible with Pyodide or pyscript, but pyodide doesn't provide an interface and pyscript is painfully slow and also doesn't provide a great editable live demo tool. This is why I built my own project on top of pyodide which lets you run editable python demos.

Check it out at [PyPrez](https://modularizer.github.io/pyprez/#useonstackoverflow) or below!

Run the javascript snippet below to see a runnable Python example:

```js
import random

x = 5

if __name__=="__main__":
    print(f"my random number is {random.random()}")

    # now produce an error to debug
    print(x[2])
```

```html
<script src="https://modularizer.github.io/pyprez/pyprez.min.js" theme="darcula"></script>
```

Comment: It took me a while to figure out that you have to click on the green arrow to run it. It would be more intuitive if you could fix it so that it runs automatically as soon as you click on "Run code snippet".

Comment: Thanks for the comment @DonaldDuck ! I've updated it now to automatically run the first time then you can click the red reload button to eidt it and then run again. It is still a bit slow the first time it loads...

Comment: Nice work! Another thing you can fix is that on my device it looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sLoJc.png) when it's done loading, so it's hard to see that it's done loading. Maybe you could fix so that it automatically scrolls down to show the results when it's done. Also for longer code snippets it might be useful to scroll down to "Loading..." while it's loading so that people can see directly that it's loading.

Comment: @DonaldDuck thanks for letting me know! I added in some logic to scroll to the bottom for now, although I'll probably work on trying to reserve more space so scrolling becomes unecessary. Note I also changed the `src` to point to a minified script and I allowed specifying Codemirror themes. I appreciate your feedback, feel free to continue to comment/contribute on the github project. I've also started a suggestions forum [here](https://github.com/modularizer/pyprez/discussions/3)

Comment: That's even better. One minor thing that you still can fix is that it would be better if it could scroll to the top of the output rather than to the bottom.