# What can I do if a user edits my post and I don't agree with the edit?

Tags: support, edits

I recently [asked a question in Stack Overflow Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/400919/is-it-possible-to-have-python-code-snippets-in-stack-overflow?noredirect=1#comment794121_400919), and in it I said - *I did Google it, and I found [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323179/please-can-we-have-runnable-python-snippets-using-skulpt) post*. Somebody with a high reputation edited it, and the user changed that line to *I did Google it, and I found [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323179/please-can-we-have-runnable-python-snippets-using-skulpt) and [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/327741/support-running-snippets-in-languages-other-than-just-javascript) post*. This should have been rejected, because I was speaking about what I found, and I hadn't seen the second post before. Is there anyway to report the person to a moderator or reject his edit or something like that?

Comment: You can reject the edit or rollback. If it's happening frequently flag the post for mod attention..

Comment: I believe Samuel did the edit in good faith, to make your question more helpful for others researching here. It doesn't actually matter if you didn't find that link yourself

Comment: You have 5 options: 1. Accept that this is how it's going to be. 2. Rollback. 3. Make a new edit. 4. Delete your post as it's no longer anything that you would have said. 5. Disassociate yourself from the post. I usually pick 4.

Comment: the person who made the edit is a moderator

Comment: @TemaniAfif How does that actually matter (besides it makes reporting harder maybe)?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ it matters because a moderator (in general) won't do random actions without justification. Knowing it's a Mod the OP can simply ping him to get more detail instead of thinking to *report the person to a moderator*

Comment: @TemaniAfif Any other editor can be pinged as well by the OP. A mod is more trusted in what they're doing, that's why I sait I believe in good faith there.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ, how can I reject it or rollback? There doesn't seem to be a button to do that.

Comment: As for the rest, I am sorry, I didn't see that it was a moderator who edited it. I thought it was the recent person named Peter. Anyway, is it considered ok to put things which you haven't seen and say that you have seen them?

Comment: And yeah, a moderator won't do random actions without justification...

Comment: @SafwanSamsudeen Rollbacks can be done from the edit history. The link to get there is just under the post.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, I saw the link now. But is it possible to remove only Samual's edit? I don't mind the new edit by Peter.

Comment: @SafwanSamsudeen _"is it considered ok to put things which you haven't seen and say that you have seen them?"_ Well, the wording could have been changed as well to make the statement more neutral, e.g. something like _There are this and this related posts._ But that's really a minor point. Usually we're interested in good content, and not in the user per se.

Comment: The question is not only for your benefit, but for future visitors. If the edit makes the question better and more useful (for example by adding more relevant links) rolling back would be a mistake and a disservice to the community.

Comment: Thanks. I think I'll just edit the wording like @πάνταῥεῖ suggested.

Comment: I'm still interested to learn what happens when we report the user Samuel Liew to the moderator Samuel Liew ... the popcorn is ready ....

Comment: @rene It's unlikely that Samuel Liew will actually review it, but if it does happen, I'll be watching.

Comment: say, could anybody tell me why this post was downvoted so badly?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I agree that the moderator shouldn't have added that link in a sentence that reads *"I found this post"*, because they're putting words in your mouth, implying you found and read that post but didn't find it helpful.

They should've posted a comment, or closed as duplicate, not edited it into that sentence.

As for your actual question, you can find the edit history of a post by clicking the edit date you find below it, you can roll the edit back from there.

Comment: Sorry, I had to unaccept your question. It would be great if you tell me what to do, but I know now through the comments, so it'll be safer for you to delete it. Thanks anyway :).

Comment: I don't know why you had to unaccept my answer, and I'm not going to remove it. It's my opinion.