# Can we have Runnable Python Snippet?

Tags: feature-request, stack-snippets

Since Python language is getting more popular, can we have Runnable Python Snippet implemented in SO?

**Why Python?**

1. It was ranked second to JavaScript/HTML/CSS in [most popular technologies in 2021](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2021#technology-most-popular-technologies).
2. It is [the second most tag used in questions](https://stackoverflow.com/tags?tab=popular) (of course, the first is JavaScript).
3. The [trend](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/trends?tags=python%2Cjavascript) of [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) tag usage in questions is now even higher than [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) tag.

From my research, there were some attempts like [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/400919/is-it-possible-to-have-python-code-snippets-in-stack-overflow) trying to make this happen in the past. However, it was never really accepted, and I am here, once again, to shout out that this should be implemented primarily for the benefits of python users in SO (hopefully other languages later).

There also was [an attempt](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323179/please-can-we-have-runnable-python-snippets-using-skulpt) suggesting using [Skulpt](https://skulpt.org/) that might be useful for the implementation of this feature if at all possible.

Comment: I've merged this into the duplicate target, my answer applied there too and the situation has not changed. Python's popularity is not the deciding factor here.